# Are there other examples of Brown-Stigler incident?

Tags: aviation-history, wwii

I have just finished reading [A Higher Call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Higher_Call) and wondered if there are other cases where a pilot showed his mercy to the foe when they are in desperate situation. Looked through several B17 related-webs, forums, and made web scrap but found none. I guess there might be some, but maybe only written in memorial of pilots.

Comment: Fantastic story. Worthwile to note that (wikipedia source) "Stigler himself flew 487 combat missions, downing 28 planes while himself being shot down 17 times (he bailed out six times and landed in a damaged plane 11 times)." (from https://portraitofwar.com/tag/jg27-franz-stigler/ ).
Being shoot down 17 times. Surviving 17 times. Air-combats for him were like a videogame :D !